# I need this image translated

Tags: translation

I'm not even sure if its chinese (I'm sorry if I'm offending someone, I'm not in touch with Chinese). I'd like to know what it means or at least some words/part of it.

[image: pic]

Comment: It is Chinese, but written in reverse order as if looked from a mirror. It's `可爱女人是用来爱的所以要`. And I tried to search the sentence on web, it seems the correct order should be `女人是用来爱的所以要可爱`, means `Women are meant to be loved so should be lovely`.

Comment: Ty very much, gladly apriciated <3.

Comment: Questions that involve translating images usually don't get a positive score.

Comment: Not a normal Chinese, suspecting that it's a register validation image or "火星文".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chinese, `可爱` means lovely, adorable.
`Women are meant to be loved so should be lovely.` is correct.

However, the word `可爱` can be split into two words: `可` and `爱`.
`可` means `... can ...` or `... be able to ...`
In most of the time, `可` implies passive voice and is not used solely.
`爱` means `love`.
Therefore, `可爱` can also mean `can be loved` or `is able to be loved`.
This meaning implies that the woman is not easily reachable. Examples of not reachable:

1. the woman in USA and the man in China and they cant move to each other
2. the woman hate the man
3. the woman is dead

So another meaning (evil) of this sentence is

`Women are meant to be loved. Do not love her. She will never love you`.